# Anyone know some Artificial muscles?

Tags: science-based, chemistry, robots

For this question, I want to have robots/androids with artificial muscles for motion. I know that there is a kind of [silicon-ethanol muscle](https://www.allaboutcircuits.com/news/silicon-based-artificial-muscles-a-new-approach-to-soft-robotics/) that works by thermal energy (the electricity boils the Ethanol, making the liquid to become gas, expand and simulate a contraction).

But nothing really useful for robots in general, nor close to Westworld silica-muscles

The only thing I can think of is [dielectric muscles](https://aip.scitation.org/doi/full/10.1063/1.4740023#:%7E:text=Dielectric%20elastomer%20(DE)%20actuators%20are,desirable%20physical%20properties%20of%20muscle.), but these need charges beyond 10kv to work.

**Are there designs currently or in development that would be suitable as artificial muscles for a robot or android?**  The goal would be to achieve something similar to artificial muscles as shown in shows such as Westworld (but not looking for an explanation of Westworld; it's just an example), functioning as muscles not hydraulics, etc.

I can imagine that the answer is a hard one, but I want to know if there is something out there that gets close enough.

Comment: If you are looking for explanation on a third party fictional world, worldbuilding is not the place to go

Comment: @L.Dutch read the question a bit more carefully, it just an example what level of capacities OP is looking for. Why single mention of a fictional example brings it in an invalid territory? Should any mentioning of Asimov or Clark works bring any q in that territory as well? OP  does not ask for ww, it another artificial muskle question looking for high performance solutions.

Comment: [For your research and interest.](https://io9.gizmodo.com/scientists-just-created-some-of-the-most-powerful-muscl-1526957560)

Comment: My heart tells me to VTC, but I'm having trouble rationalizing it. Please pay attention to my reasons. Qs about 3rd party/commercial worlds are off-topic. Asking "I want Star Wars light sabers in my world, how can I do that?" is valid because it's a question about the rules of your world. That's worldbuilding because you own the world and its rules. But you're asking what real-world tech can reflect a 3rd-party world. Now the question is just a research effort, and that's not quite what SE's about. Worst of all, the answer is "none" unless you're willing to allow pneumatic (\*continued\*)

Comment: ... or hydraulic pistons and motors, there isn't anything that's "close enough." Maybe if you defined (very specifically!) what "close enough" means because, frankly, pistons and motors are close enough to "muscles" to achieve the desired effect in robots and there are plenty of examples in the world today to demonstrate that. Honestly, the question doesn't feel like you're building your own world - and that's what has me on edge - but the question is just vague enough to not cross that line. But that's a down-vote reason. So I'm going to down vote instead.

Comment: What's wrong with hydraulics or electric motors? Hydraulics and motors are what we use for muscles in our muscular machines, such as excavators, graders or backhoes. And, of course, in our robots.

Comment: Fishing line artificial muscles https://science.sciencemag.org/content/343/6173/868

Comment: @JBH Have seen that "research q" argument made by someone else as well, point some relevant meta and I can write more, but short version there are many legit wb questions which are of that kind. OP's call for expertiese of present answerers to do it faster and better+their interpretation. SE in general tries to be the end place for users google activities, so such reason should not be a vtc reason. There are low effort q's which didn't homework at all, but even then it makes sense only if it gets in the way to produce answers, and it should be sorted out in comment section prior that.

Comment: @AlexP I don't think there's anything wrong with them. Did I misread the question? I got the impression the OP was only looking for artificial muscles that reflected the actual expression of motion that our biological muscles have. If I misread the Q, I'll delete my comments - they were made from that perspective. (Although I'm still bothered that this feels like the OP is building a 3rd party world....)

Comment: I've got no idea what Westworld is. Rather than referring to a third party by name, just describe briefly what it's like or how it functions. You could put Westworld in a footnote if you really must, but please add a link so we can understand better what you're after! Also, you might want to make a brief introduction to your invented world: what's it like, what its tech level is, how easy or difficult you expect this aspect of your world to be from within.

Comment: @JBH: ? My comment was directed to the original poster, to remind them that the question would be much improved if they explained why the traditional solutions won't work for them, and listed the missing functionalities. Did I ping you by mistake?

Comment: Reactive polymers or vitrimers. See [moving polymer strip] (https://youtu.be/oa4M2b7Ewsg) You can also do this with heat, salinity and electric charge. Sadly I don't have the time right now to develop it into a full answer, maybe later.

Comment: @AlexP Ah-hah! I apologize. The OP had mentioned nothing about hydraulics or electric motors, but I did. So I jumped to a conclusion. Sorry!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is a group at UC Boulder working on Artificial muscles (https://doi.org/10.1002/adma.202003375) that are made out of small, aligned plastic pouches which contain an electrostatic fluid which expands and contracts upon creating a potential difference across all pouches.

By designing pouches in various shapes and by changing the fluid volume, various contractions can be developed to increase the degrees of freedom i.e. more types of movements.

Answer (score 3):

You need to look up Festo. They're the company behind those viral youtube videos of flying penguins and birds.

Most of their products are normal servos and actuators - electrical, pneumatic and hydraulic. Their experimental stuff are meme worthy (just [search for "festo" on youtube](https://www.youtube.com/results?search_query=festo)) . However, they do sell this pneumatic muscle: [https://www.festo.com/us/en/p/fluidic-muscle-id_DMSP/?q=~:festoSortOrderScored](https://www.festo.com/us/en/p/fluidic-muscle-id_DMSP/?q=%7E:festoSortOrderScored)

[image: Festo Fluidic Muscle]

You can see a simple demo of this on youtube: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=2iG1ybuchx0

Their commercial muscle is quite large. However they have made experimental muscles that are tiny. Of course, you would need a full pneumatic or hydraulic infrastructure to expand and contract these muscles but you can hide the pumps, valves etc. in the robot's body as organs. In fact if you searched youtube like I mentioned above you would find example robots from Festo themselves that they use as demos at trade shows.

Comment: Also, [Shadow Dexterous Hand](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shadow_Hand). Has been here for quite a while.